# What tools are there for functional programming in C?

Tags: c, functional-programming

I've been thinking a lot lately about how to go about doing functional programming in C (*not* C++).  Obviously, C is a procedural language and doesn't really support functional programming natively.

Are there any compiler/language extensions that add some functional programming constructs to the language?  GCC provides [nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) as a language extension; nested functions can access variables from the parent stack frame, but this is still a long way away from mature closures.

For example, one thing that I think could be really useful in C is that anywhere where a function pointer is expected, you could be able to pass a lambda expression, creating a closure which decays into a function pointer.  C++0x is going to include lambda expressions (which I think is awesome); however, I'm looking for tools applicable to straight C.

[Edit] To clarify, I'm not trying to solve a particular problem in C that would be more suited to functional programming; I'm merely curious about what tools are out there if I wanted to do so.

Comment: Instead of looking for hacks and non-portable extensions to try to turn C into something it's not, why don't you just use a language that provides the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: See also related question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995/is-there-a-functional-language-for-c-ecosystem>

Comment: @AndyBrice That question is about a different language and doesn't actually appear to make sense (C++ doesn't have an "ecosystem" in the same sense as.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[FFCALL](http://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall.html) lets you build closures in C -- `callback = alloc_callback(&function, data)` returns a function pointer such that `callback(arg1, ...)` is equivalent to calling `function(data, arg1, ...)`.  You will have to handle garbage collection manually, though.

Relatedly, [blocks](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2008-August/002670.html) have been added to Apple's fork of GCC; they're not function pointers, but they let you pass around lambdas while avoiding the need to build and free storage for captured variables by hand (effectively, some copying and reference counting happens, hidden behind some syntactic sugar and runtime libraries).

Answer (score 101):

You can use GCC's nested functions to simulate lambda expressions, in fact, I have a macro to do it for me:

```
#define lambda(return_type, function_body) \
  ({ \
    return_type anon_func_name_ function_body \
    anon_func_name_; \
  })
```

Use like this:

```
int (*max)(int, int) = lambda (int, (int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; });
```

Comment: This is really cool. It seems `__fn__` is just arbitrary name for the function defined within the block `({` ... `})`, not some GCC extension or predefined macro? The choice of name for `__fn__` (looking very much like GCC definition) really made me scratch my head and search the GCC documentation for no good effect.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn’t work in practice: if you want the closure to capture anything, it requires an executable stack, which is a terrible security practice.  Personally, I don’t think it is useful at all.

Comment: It's not remotely useful, but it is fun. That's why the other answer is accepted.

Answer (score 94):

Functional programming is not about lambdas, it is all about pure functions.  So the following broadly promote functional style:

1. Only use function arguments, do not use global state.
2. Minimise side effects i.e. printf, or any IO.  Return data describing IO which can be executed instead of causing the side effects directly in all functions.

This can be achieved in plain c, no need for magic.

Comment: I think you have taken that extreme view of functional programming to the point of absurdity. What good is a pure specification of, e.g., `map`, if one does not have the facilities to pass a function to it?

Comment: I think this approach is far more pragmatic than using macros to create a functional language inside c.  Using pure functions appropriately is more likely to improve a system than using map instead of for loops.

Comment: Surely you know that map is just the starting point. Without first-class functions, any program (even if all its functions are 'pure') will be lower-order (in the information theory sense) than its equivalent with first-class functions. In my view, it is this declarative style only possible with first-class functions that is the main benefit of FP. I think you be doing someone a disservice to imply that the verbosity that results from lack of first-class functions is all FP has to offer. It should be noted that historically the term FP implied first-class funcs more than purity.

Comment: P.S. Previous comment was from mobile-- irregular grammar was not intentional.

Comment: I'm not against first class functions, I use them everyday and wouldn't do without them.  Never in c though, good luck with that.

Comment: Isn't that called "pure functional programming"? I would say functional programming is about thinking of a program as recursive compositions of functions, and purity is orthogonal to it. Purity helps you (or a computer) reason about it, for proof of correctness and for optimization. First-class functions are necessary, I think, to do useful things or at least do them nicely, but not sufficient.

Comment: Andy Tills answer displays a very pragmatic view on things. Going "Pure" in C does not require anything fancy and yields a great benefit. First class functions, in comparison accounts to "comfort living". It is convenient, but adopting a pure style of programming is practical. I wonder why no one discusses tail calls in relation to all this. Those who want first class functions should also ask for tail calls.

Answer (score 21):

Hartel & Muller's book, *Functional C*, can nowadays (2012-01-02) be found at: http://eprints.eemcs.utwente.nl/1077/ (there is a link to PDF version).

Comment: There's no attempt at anything functional in this book (as related to the question).

Comment: It seems you are quite right. Indeed, the preface states the purpose of the book is to teach imperative programming after student has already familiarized herself with functional programming. 

FYI, this was my first answer in SO and it was written as an answer only because I did not have required reputation to comment a previous answer with rotten link. I always wonder why people keep +1 this answer... Please do not do that! :-)

Comment: Perhaps the book should have been better called Post-Functional Programming (first of all because "Imperative C" does not sound sexy, secondly because it assumes familiarity with functional programming paradigm, thirdly as a pun because the imperative paradigm seems like decline of standards and correct functionality, and perhaps fourth to refer to Larry Wall's notion of postmodern programming - though this book was written before Larry Wall's article/presentation).

Comment: And this is a duplicate answer

Answer (score 13):

Prerequisite for functional programming style is a first class function.
It could be simulated in portable C if you tolerate next:

- manual management of lexical scope bindings, aka closures.
- manual management of function variables lifetime.
- alternative syntax of function application/call.

```c
/* 
 * with constraints desribed above we could have
 * good approximation of FP style in plain C
 */

int increment_int(int x) {
  return x + 1;
}

WRAP_PLAIN_FUNCTION_TO_FIRST_CLASS(increment, increment_int);

map(increment, list(number(0), number(1)); // --> list(1, 2)


/* composition of first class function is also possible */

function_t* computation = compose(
  increment,
  increment,
  increment
);

*(int*) call(computation, number(1)) == 4;
```

runtime for such code could be as small as one below

```
struct list_t {
  void* head;
  struct list_t* tail;
};

struct function_t {
   void* (*thunk)(list_t*);
   struct list_t* arguments;
}

void* apply(struct function_t* fn, struct list_t* arguments) {
  return fn->thunk(concat(fn->arguments, arguments));
}

/* expansion of WRAP_PLAIN_FUNCTION_TO_FIRST_CLASS */
void* increment_thunk(struct list_t* arguments) {
  int x_arg = *(int*) arguments->head;
  int value = increment_int(x_arg);
  int* number = malloc(sizeof *number);

  return number ? (*number = value, number) : NULL;
}

struct function_t* increment = &(struct function_t) {
  increment_thunk,
  NULL
};

/* call(increment, number(1)) expands to */
apply(increment, &(struct list_t) { number(1), NULL });
```

In essence we imitate first class function with closures represented as pair of function/arguments plus bunch of macroses. Complete code could be found [here](https://github.com/viktor-shepel/frunzik).

Answer (score 11):

The main thing that comes to mind is the use of code generators.  Would you be willing to program in a different language that provided the functional programming and then generate the C code from that?

If that's not an attractive option, then you could abuse CPP to get part of the way there.  The macro system should let you emulate some functional programming ideas.  I've heard tell that gcc is implemented this way but I've never checked.

C can of course pass functions around using function pointers, the main problems are lack of closures and the type system tends to get in the way.  You could explore more powerful macro systems than CPP such as M4.  I guess ultimately, what I'm suggesting is that true C isn't up to the task without great effort but you could extend C to make it be up to the task.  That extension would look the most like C if you use CPP or you could go to the other end of the spectrum and generate C code from some other language.

Comment: This is the most honest answer.  Trying to write C in a functional manner is to fight against the language design and structure itself.

Answer (score 7):

The way I went about doing functional programming in C was to write a functional language interpreter in C.  I named it Fexl, which is short for "Function EXpression Language."

The interpreter is very small, compiling down to 68K on my system with -O3 enabled.  It's not a toy either - I'm using it for all the new production code I write for my business (web-based accounting for investment partnerships.)

Now I write C code only to (1) add a built-in function that calls a system routine (e.g. fork, exec, setrlimit, etc.), or (2) optimize a function that could otherwise be written in Fexl (e.g. search for a substring).

The module mechanism is based on the concept of a "context".  A context is a function (written in Fexl) which maps a symbol to its definition.  When you read a Fexl file, you can resolve it with any context you like.  This allows you to create custom environments, or run code in a restricted "sandbox."

http://fexl.com

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement closures, you'll have to get groady with assembly language and stack swapping/management. Not recommending against it, just saying that's what you'll have to do.

Not sure how you'll handle anonymous functions in C. On a von Neumann machine, you could do anonymous functions in asm, though.

Answer (score 5):

Look at Hartel & Muller's book, *Functional C*

- https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/5128727/book.pdf
- [http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~henkm/f2c/index.html](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/%7Ehenkm/f2c/index.html) — missing since 2016
- [http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~henkm/f2c/index.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20100108015544/http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/%7Ehenkm/f2c/index.html) — via Internet Archive aka WayBack Machine.

Answer (score 3):

The [Felix language](http://www.felix-lang.org/) compiles to C++. Maybe that could be a step stone, if you don't mind C++.

Comment: ⁻¹ because α)The author explicitly mentioned «not C++», β)The C++ produced by a compiler wouldn't be a «human readable C++». γ)C++ standard supports a functional programming, no need to use a compiler from one language to another.

Comment: Once you come up with a functional language by means of macros or alike, you automatically imply that you do not care so much for C. This answer is valid and okay because even C++ started out as a macro party on top of C. If you go down that road far enough, you will end up with a new language. Then it is only coming down to a back end discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Well quite a few programming languages are written in C. And some of them support functions as first class citizens, languages in that area are ecl (embbedabble common lisp IIRC), Gnu Smalltalk (gst) (Smalltalk has blocks), then there are libraries for "closures" e.g in glib2 http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/chapter-signal.html#closure 
which at least got near functional programming. So maybe using some of those implementations to do functional programming may be an option.

Well  or you can go learning Ocaml, Haskell, Mozart/Oz or the like ;-)

Regards

Comment: Would you mind to tell me what's so terrible wrong with using libraries which well at least support the FP style of programming?

Answer (score -2):

What is it about C that you want to make functional, the syntax or the semantics? The semantics of functional programming could certainly be added to the C compiler, but by the time you were done, you'd essentially have the equivalent of one of the existing functional languages, such as Scheme, Haskell, etc.

It would be a better use of time to just learn the syntax of those languages which directly support those semantics.

Answer (score -3):

Dont Know about C. There are some functional features in Objective-C though, GCC on the OSX also supports some features, however I would again recommend to start using a functional language, there are plenty mentioned above. I personally started off with scheme, there are some excellent books such as The Little Schemer that can help you do so.

Comment: Objective-C is not C though. and your reply i think doesn't answer the question