# Functional programming in C using linked list

Tags: c, functional-programming

How would you do a functionally pure linked list in C? Is a linked list what I should even be doing? I'm trying to have a list of objects but I can't think of how to add an item to the list from a function without modifying outside states.

I basically want this:

`void AddItemToList(Item item);`

To be able to be called from anywhere, without the caller having to worry about what list is being added to.

Right now I just have:

```
void AddTypeToList(entityType_t *type, entityType_t *listHead)
{
    type->next = listHead;
    listHead = type;
}

void RegisterEntityType(entityType_t *type)
{
    AddTypeToList(type, typeList);
}
```

But this is obviously not functional (or is it?) because `RegisterEntityType` is modifying `typeList`. (which is a global `entityType_t`)

Comment: To have a functional linkedlist you would have to reconstruct the entire list with the extra element, or have a reverse linkedlist where you can just add the add the element to the front.

Comment: If you're serious about functional programming on data structures you should be familiar with this -- http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf -- if you are not already.  A more polished version is available in book form, same author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a different function, generically speaking,

```
List AddItemToList(List list, Item item);
```

Because you should return a new list with the item added, without modifying the original list. This involves other questions, such as that a Garbage Collector should be needed in order to keep track of the intermediate lists your are going to create and discard.

I don't think that C is the best language to implement functional programming techniques, you'll have to build everything from the ground up. The obvious, ideal choice would be a pure functional programming language, or at least a programming language with support for functional techniques, such as for example C++, C# or Python.

Maybe you would like to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216037/what-tools-are-there-for-functional-programming-in-c).

Hope this (somehow) helps.